# Inserting VLOOKUP into spreadsheet using VBA but having table array length adjustable

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Let me preface by saying I'm very new to VBA and understand there could be easier, cleaner ways to go about this, but here we go:

I have this equation:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],R2C16:R188C16,1,FALSE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q2", "Q" & CellNumber), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

It inserts A VLOOKUP equation and compares a column 3 columns over to a table array. It then autofills down to the CellNumber variable length.

The problem is that I want the table array length to be adjustable and use CellNumber in the VLOOKUP equation so that it changes accordingly.

But... I'm having no luck making it work...

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Maybe all you need is this? `Range("Q2", "Q" & CellNumber).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],R2C16:R" & CellNumber & "C16,1,FALSE)"`

Comment: Thanks @andyholaday, that was perfect. Plus now I can go through my clunky code and remove lots of unnecessary similar looking equations.

Comment: @pnuts my pleasure. Thanks for minding the shop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was acknowledged as a solution in the comments:

```
Range("Q2", "Q" & CellNumber).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],R2C16:R" & CellNumber & "C16,1,FALSE)"
```